# How to report on a specific survey question/response per case owner?

Tags: survey, salesforce-survey

I need to create a report on survey response per case owner. (I specifically looking at a certain question/response - but all will do)

I assume the object I need is:

```
Name:   SurveyQuestionResponse
Label:  Survey Question Response 
Id: 0Kr
```

But I don't see that in the object definition.

According to the data model:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_salesforce_surveys_object_model.htm

I can get the case from the invitation Id, but don't see a way to do that.

Any help is appreciated.